# How to change Balloon Marker image in ios-charts?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bar-chart, ios-charts

My Chart balloon is being cut from bounds of screen [image: Like this]
so how i can change arrow of image [image: Like this]
is it possible to change arrow of marker (arrow to leftside/right side) as display in image ?

This balloon marker is drawn by CGContext and its code as below

```
CGContextSaveGState(context)
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color?.CGColor)
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width,
        rect.origin.y)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - arrowSize.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width + arrowSize.width) / 2.0,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - arrowSize.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x + rect.size.width / 2.0,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x + (rect.size.width - arrowSize.width) / 2.0,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - arrowSize.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y + rect.size.height - arrowSize.height)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,
        rect.origin.x,
        rect.origin.y)
    CGContextFillPath(context)
```

This code is written in balloon-marker.swift file

Comment: I've seen an issue which is already closed here: https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts/issues/364, probably may help!!! But I would recommend write your own marker with layout you need or use delegate from the chart like -didHighlightValue (dont remember exact name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The balloon marker is just an example of how you can use it. The `ChartMarker` class has a few properties, among which is `image` property. You can directly use it to display any of your images.

What you need to think about is the position and size. You are responsible to decide the location and size, since the default implementation is:

```
/// Draws the ChartMarker on the given position on the given context
public func draw(context context: CGContext, point: CGPoint)
{
    let offset = self.offsetForDrawingAtPos(point)
    let size = self.size

    let rect = CGRect(x: point.x + offset.x, y: point.y + offset.y, width: size.width, height: size.height)

    UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
    image!.drawInRect(rect)
    UIGraphicsPopContext()
}
```

You see it just draws the image at `x: point.x + offset.x, y: point.y + offset.y`, with `width: size.width, height: size.height`

You can simply create your sub class of `ChartMarker` and do the customization by overriding `draw(context context: CGContext, point: CGPoint)`

If you don't want to use images, then you have to use CoreGraphics as you have seen to draw the shape you like. Still, you are responsible to decide how to draw the shape.

About the being cutted on screen edge, it's another question, because your shape is too large to display in the center. Either change the size or change your shape direction and so on to solve it, it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot wingzero